# Помогите с получением данных из строки, парсинг

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Здравствуте, пишу программу на Python, строки с сайта получил, такого вида:

```
<source src="https://link/to/video" type="application/x-mpegURL" resolution="1080">
```

Нужно на выходе получить значения https://link/to/video и 1080.
Помогите, думаю через регулярные надо, но в них почти не разбираюсь.

Comment: какой библиотекой парсишь?

Comment: Регулярки для парсинга `html` это самое худшее решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться библиотекой `bs4`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    html = '<source src="https://link/to/video" type="application/x-mpegURL" resolution="1080">'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    source = soup.source

    src = source['src']
    resolution = source['resolution']

    print(f'{src} и {resolution}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
https://link/to/video и 1080
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from re import compile
s = '<source src="https://link/to/video" type="application/x-mpegURL" resolution="1080">'
r = compile("(\S+)=[\"']?((?:.(?![\"']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>\"']))+.)[\"']?")

out = dict(r.findall(s))
print(out['src'], out['resolution'])
```